# Remove duplicate tuples from SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table that looks like the following :

```
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 |, etc...
```

I want to remove all the second pairs to get the following result

```
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |, etc...
```

Comment: Your data is not clear: Could you have a record such as `a=6, b=5` but without a corresponding `a=5, b=6`, in which case the `a=6, b=5` would be included in your resultset? That is, you want the "combinations" of values without all the "permutations"?

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicates from the table, or simply select distinct combinations? These are two different things...

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is:

```
select a, b
from t
where a < b;
```

This assumes that all pairs are represented.

If they are not, you can extend this:

```
select a, b
from t
where a < b or
      (b < a and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.a = t.b and t2.b = t.a)
      );
```

This keeps all rows where `a < b` and also all rows where `a > b` if there is no corresponding row with the `a` and `b` values switched.

Comment: Please explain your `(b < a and not exists..` part of the query.

Comment: This was where I was going with my comment to the OP above.

Comment: @ArupRakshit If you have (1,2) and (2,1) just take (1,2) (a<b) solve the problem. But you also check (2,1) and if (1,2) doesn't exist then is also included.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Your explanation is much better than the original answer edited explanation.. +1 . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN a < b THEN a ELSE b END as a,
                 CASE WHEN a < b THEN b ELSE a END as b
 FROM yourTable
```

Here if you have (1,2) and (2,1) you end with (1,2)

But if you only have (2,1) also end with (1,2)

Answer (score 1):

With a self join:

```
select distinct t.*
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.a = t.b and tt.b = t.a
where tt.a is null or t.a <= t.b
```

it covers the case where not all rows have a pair row such like a = b and b = a and the case where in one row a = b.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j9sj8opjPL6DWMCrvBdj69/2).

```
    CREATE TABLE tablename (
      `a` INTEGER,
      `b` INTEGER
    );

    INSERT INTO tablename
      (`a`, `b`)
    VALUES
      ('1', '2'),
      ('2', '1'),
      ('3', '4'),
      ('4', '3'),
      ('5', '6'),
      ('8', '7'),
      ('9', '9'),
      ('9', '9');

    | a   | b   |
    | --- | --- |
    | 1   | 2   |
    | 3   | 4   |
    | 5   | 6   |
    | 8   | 7   |
    | 9   | 9   |
```